# Browser specific text-layout bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, cross-browser

A fellow developer and I are on exactly the same Firefox version (41.0.1) using the exact same steps to reproduce a text-layout bug on our web application after hard cache refreshes using the same production server (no local assets), and he sees the bug but I don't.  We tried on a 3rd developer's browser (same Firefox version) and he does not see the bug, so it seems isolated to this one browser instance.  Both machines are identical - Windows 7 on Lenovo Thinkpad T420.  It's a CSS text layout bug - text overflows the box onto multiple lines.  I've linked to an image below.

[Image of bug here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR64s.png)

We have also tried:

- Running the problem browser in private browsing mode.
- Starting the problem browser in safe-mode (to disable plugins).
- Doing a diff between the CSS source file each browser is seeing - they are binary equal

Does anyone have any ideas why this might happen or how else to try to debug it?

Edits:
Other things we have tried:

- Reset zoom levels on both (ctrl+0)

Comment: Please include the relevant code to allow us to attempt to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Run the abberant instance with extensions disabled

Comment: 1: reset zoom to 100% an all systems (solves 80% of the time)
2: are you all on the same OS? windows / osx / linux all render fonts differently

Comment: Good thoughts, I forgot to mention we checked the zoom level and both machines are identical.  I just made the edits to the question.

Comment: Have you disabled all third-party add-ons?

Comment: We have tried to debug in safe-mode (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode), which I believe disables all add-ons and extensions.  The bug is still there.